# Is it possible to group document by key instead of value in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, querying

I am trying to group document by key instead of value in elastic search. This is an example of what  I have:

```
{
...

"body": {
    "ml_en": "Some Text"
}

...
}

{
...

"body": {
    "ml_en": "Some Text"
}

...
}

{
...

"body": {
    "ml_lv": "Some Text"
}

...
}
```

And this is the expected result:

ml_en: 2,
ml_lv: 1

Comment: So does a doc having value in `ml_en` field not have value in `ml_lv` field?

Comment: Yes, its a dynamic field according to the language. It can be anything in this format ml_*

Comment: No I mean does every document have a value in the field or say document with value in "ml_en" does not have value in "ml_lv".

Comment: No, every document has value and in one document there is only one key pair "body": {
    "ml_en": "English"
}

...
}

{
...

"body": {
    "ml_bg": "Български"
}